# How can I extract values from one column to form two or more new columns?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 columns the first one contains values and the second one attributes for those values.

I want to create new columns for each attribute in order to visualize it accordingly.

It should look something like this when I am done.

[image]

Thanks for your help :)

I tried to use an if statement to create my column. It had the purpose to insert the value into the cell, when it returns true and an empty string when it returns false. But I cannot use the [Value] column for that purpose.

Actual= if(FIND ("Actual",[Column1],1,0)>0, [Values],"")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is in powerquery then add column ... custom column

```
= if [Column 1] = "Actual" then [Values] else null
```

and then add another custom column with

```
= if [Column 1] = "Optimal" then [Values] else null
```

or instead of above, you could

add column .. index column ... 
click select Column 1
Transform .. Pivot Column...  and choose Values as the values column